# How to implement hidden interface with reflection in android JAVA?

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-camera

I would like to use android.filterfw.* framworks in android 4.0 later. but, it is still hidden in SDK.
so, now I am trying JAVA reflection-tricks.

do anyone know how to implement hidden interface with reflection in android JAVA ?

I want to mimic the following code with reflection.

```
private SurfaceTextureSourceListener mSourceReadyCallback = new SurfaceTextureSourceListener() {
    public void onSurfaceTextureSourceReady(SurfaceTexture source) {

    }
};

mGraphEnv.addReferences("textureSourceCallback", mSourceReadyCallback);
```

I did this one.

```
Class c = Class.forName("android.filterpacks.videosrc.SurfaceTextureSource$SurfaceTextureSourceListener"); //step 1
instance = c.newInstance(); //step 2
proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(instance.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] { instance.getClass() }, mHandler); //step 3

InvocationHandler mHandler = new InvocationHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

    //TODO

    return method.invoke(instance, args);
   }
};
```

then, I got an exception on "step 2".  OK, I understand I can't create an instance of interface directory.
so, my question is how to implement hidden interface with reflection.

I can not do something like this...

```
public class MyIPL implements SurfaceTextureSourceListener {

}
```

do you know any ideas ?